# I want to add a Member to a class while program is running c#

Tags: c#

Im trying to add a member to a class while the program is running. What i mean by this is i have this class

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValorantAgent JettDescription = new ValorantAgent("Jett", "dash", "updraft", "smoke", "duelist");
        ValorantAgent OmenDescription = new ValorantAgent("Omen", "smoke", "teleport", "flash", "controller");
        ValorantAgent BreachDescription = new ValorantAgent("Breach", "seismic blast", "flash", "fusion charge", "initiator");
        ValorantAgent ReynaDescription = new ValorantAgent("Reyna", "dismiss", "devour", "leer", "duelist");
        ValorantAgent SovaDescription = new ValorantAgent("Sova", "Tracker dart", "Shock dart", "Drone", "Initiator");
        ValorantAgent BrimstoneDescription = new ValorantAgent("Brimstone", "Smoke", "Molly", "Stim Becon", "Controller");
        ValorantAgent ViperDescription = new ValorantAgent("Viper", "Toxic Screen", "Poison Cloud", "Toxic Molly", "Controller");
        ValorantAgent PhoenixDescription = new ValorantAgent("Phoenix", "Fire Molly", "Flash", "Fire Wall", "Duelist");
        ValorantAgent RazeDescription = new ValorantAgent("Raze", "Grenade", "Boom Bot", "Blast Pack", "Duelist");
        ValorantAgent SageDescription = new ValorantAgent("Sage", "Healing Orb", "Slow Orb", "Wall", "Sentinal");
        ValorantAgent CypherDescription = new ValorantAgent("Cypher", "Camera", "tripwire", "Cage", "Sentinal");
        ValorantAgent KillJoyDescription = new ValorantAgent("KillJoy", "Turret", "Molly", "Alarmbot", "Sentinal");

        int PlayerChoise = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello User, What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] See curent agents");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Add a agent");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Exit");

        PlayerChoise = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       

        switch(PlayerChoise)
        {
            case 1:

                Console.Clear();


                Console.WriteLine("Pick an agent");

                string[] Agents = { "Jett", "Omen", "Breach", "Reyna", "Sova", "Brimstone", "Viper", "Phoenix", "Raze", "Sage", "Cypher", "Killjoy" };

                for (int i = 0; i < Agents.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {Agents[i]}");
                }

                int Selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                string selectedAgent = Agents[Selection];

                Console.WriteLine($"You selected {selectedAgent}");

                switch (selectedAgent.ToLower())
                {
                    case "jett":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {JettDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {JettDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {JettDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {JettDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {JettDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "omen":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {OmenDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {OmenDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "breach":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {BreachDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {BreachDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "reyna":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {ReynaDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {ReynaDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "sova":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {SovaDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {SovaDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "brimstone":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "viper":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {ViperDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {ViperDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "phoenix":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {PhoenixDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {PhoenixDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "raze":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {RazeDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {RazeDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "sage":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {SageDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {SageDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {SageDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {SageDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {SageDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "cypher":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {CypherDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {CypherDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "killJoy":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {KillJoyDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {KillJoyDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                }
                break; //case 1/see current agents break
            case 2://add agent case
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Coming soon!");
                

                break; //case 2/add agent break
        }







        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and want to add a "valorantAgent" to this class while the program is running. So when the user uses the program it asks them if the want to see the current list of "ValorantAgents" or if they want to add a "ValorantAgent". this is my main code.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValorantAgent JettDescription = new ValorantAgent("Jett", "dash", "updraft", "smoke", "duelist");
        ValorantAgent OmenDescription = new ValorantAgent("Omen", "smoke", "teleport", "flash", "controller");
        ValorantAgent BreachDescription = new ValorantAgent("Breach", "seismic blast", "flash", "fusion charge", "initiator");
        ValorantAgent ReynaDescription = new ValorantAgent("Reyna", "dismiss", "devour", "leer", "duelist");
        ValorantAgent SovaDescription = new ValorantAgent("Sova", "Tracker dart", "Shock dart", "Drone", "Initiator");
        ValorantAgent BrimstoneDescription = new ValorantAgent("Brimstone", "Smoke", "Molly", "Stim Becon", "Controller");
        ValorantAgent ViperDescription = new ValorantAgent("Viper", "Toxic Screen", "Poison Cloud", "Toxic Molly", "Controller");
        ValorantAgent PhoenixDescription = new ValorantAgent("Phoenix", "Fire Molly", "Flash", "Fire Wall", "Duelist");
        ValorantAgent RazeDescription = new ValorantAgent("Raze", "Grenade", "Boom Bot", "Blast Pack", "Duelist");
        ValorantAgent SageDescription = new ValorantAgent("Sage", "Healing Orb", "Slow Orb", "Wall", "Sentinal");
        ValorantAgent CypherDescription = new ValorantAgent("Cypher", "Camera", "tripwire", "Cage", "Sentinal");
        ValorantAgent KillJoyDescription = new ValorantAgent("KillJoy", "Turret", "Molly", "Alarmbot", "Sentinal");

        int PlayerChoise = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello User, What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] See curent agents");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Add a agent");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Exit");

        PlayerChoise = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       

        switch(PlayerChoise)
        {
            case 1:

                Console.Clear();


                Console.WriteLine("Pick an agent");

                string[] Agents = { "Jett", "Omen", "Breach", "Reyna", "Sova", "Brimstone", "Viper", "Phoenix", "Raze", "Sage", "Cypher", "Killjoy" };

                for (int i = 0; i < Agents.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {Agents[i]}");
                }

                int Selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                string selectedAgent = Agents[Selection];

                Console.WriteLine($"You selected {selectedAgent}");

                switch (selectedAgent.ToLower())
                {
                    case "jett":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {JettDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {JettDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {JettDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {JettDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {JettDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "omen":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {OmenDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {OmenDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {OmenDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "breach":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {BreachDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {BreachDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {BreachDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "reyna":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {ReynaDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {ReynaDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {ReynaDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "sova":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {SovaDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {SovaDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {SovaDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "brimstone":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {BrimstoneDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "viper":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {ViperDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {ViperDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {ViperDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "phoenix":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {PhoenixDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {PhoenixDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {PhoenixDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "raze":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {RazeDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {RazeDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {RazeDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "sage":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {SageDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {SageDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {SageDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {SageDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {SageDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "cypher":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {CypherDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {CypherDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {CypherDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                    case "killJoy":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {KillJoyDescription.AgentName}, Ability 1: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {KillJoyDescription.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {KillJoyDescription.AgentType}");
                        break;
                }
                break; //case 1/see current agents break
            case 2://add agent case
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Coming soon!");
                

                break; //case 2/add agent break
        }







        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of named ValorantAgents as members of your class, add a`Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent>` (where the string is the name). Then add your various ValorantAgents at startup. That way you can add more on the fly (and get rid of them on they fly if you want to)

Comment: why do not store them in a list? like `List<ValorantAgent> ValorantAgents` so it could store all them and when you add a new agent, just add a item to list, OR you could use a `Dictionary<>`

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you, I will be using this in the future although I still would like to know if its even possible to do what I'm asking (added a member to a class through the console). Let me know if you need more information about the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Blue I'm still very new to coding (started about 2 weeks ago)  and haven't learned about list yet, thank you for the advice though!

Comment: Well you can (by inheriting from `Expando`), but it all you want is a bunch of ValorantAgents, then a Dictionary or a List is the way to go (type-safety has its advantages)

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you! i will be checking out Expando tomorrow because it is very late lol. Do you know if its possible to add a member to a class through the console?

Comment: You state that… _”and haven't learned about list yet”_ … ? Then what “collection” types have you covered? This obviously is in need of a “collection” type structure. Therefore, any “collection” type you use is irrelevant to how your current code ignores the simple OOP “CLASS” structure. What you are wanting to do can be easily solved if you made a `ValorantAgent` class with three properties… `Name`, `Type` and a “collection” of `Abilities`. This will not only simplify your current code, but will solve your issue of creating a new `ValorantAgant` agent on the fly.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but in c# you cannot just add members to a class because c# is a statically typed language. It has something called `ExpandoObject` that may interest you. However, if you need to add a member at runtime, it means you're possibly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are heading down the wrong path (See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Rather than adding members, you should use a [`Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) to store pairs of the agents' names, and the agent objects. With a dictionary, you will be able to access agent objects by their name. You will also be able to get rid of that big switch statement.

Rather than declaring all those fields of type `ValorantAgent`, declare one `Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent>`, and put everything in it using a [collection initialiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent> agents = new Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent> {
    {"Jett", new ValorantAgent("Jett", "dash", "updraft", "smoke", "duelist")},
    {"Omen", new ValorantAgent("Omen", "smoke", "teleport", "flash", "controller")},
    {"Breach", new ValorantAgent("Breach", "seismic blast", "flash", "fusion charge", "initiator")},
    {"Reyna", new ValorantAgent("Reyna", "dismiss", "devour", "leer", "duelist")},
    {"Sova", new ValorantAgent("Sova", "Tracker dart", "Shock dart", "Drone", "Initiator")},
    {"Brimstone", new ValorantAgent("Brimstone", "Smoke", "Molly", "Stim Becon", "Controller")},
    {"Viper", new ValorantAgent("Viper", "Toxic Screen", "Poison Cloud", "Toxic Molly", "Controller")},
    {"Phoenix", new ValorantAgent("Phoenix", "Fire Molly", "Flash", "Fire Wall", "Duelist")},
    {"Raze", new ValorantAgent("Raze", "Grenade", "Boom Bot", "Blast Pack", "Duelist")},
    {"Sage", new ValorantAgent("Sage", "Healing Orb", "Slow Orb", "Wall", "Sentinal")},
    {"Cypher", new ValorantAgent("Cypher", "Camera", "tripwire", "Cage", "Sentinal")},
    {"KillJoy", new ValorantAgent("KillJoy", "Turret", "Molly", "Alarmbot", "Sentinal")}
};
```

Now, rather than saying `JettDescription`, you can instead say `agents["Jett"]`.

The first case of the outer switch statement can now be much shortened:

```
string[] agentsNames = { "Jett", "Omen", "Breach", "Reyna", "Sova", "Brimstone", "Viper", "Phoenix", "Raze", "Sage", "Cypher", "Killjoy" };

int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// you might want to check whether selection is out of range first...
ValorantAgent selectedAgent = agents[agentsNames[selection]];

Console.WriteLine($"You selected {selectedAgent.AgentName}");

Console.WriteLine($"Name: {selectedAgent.AgentName}, Ability 1: {selectedAgent.AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {selectedAgent.AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {selectedAgent.AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {selectedAgent.AgentType}");
break;
```

Note how the selected agent's name is first retrieved using `agentsNames[selection]`, then that name is used to access the `agents` dictionary, forming the expression `agents[agentsNames[selection]]`.

And it's now very simple to add a new agent:

```
ValorantAgent newAgent = new ValorantAgent(...);
agents.Add(newAgent.AgentName, newAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code were written in a different way, this task would be much easier. In general, when you have many of the same kinds of objects, it's not very wise to create single variables for each of them.

You could make use of data structures to help you greatly. In particular, a Dictionary would be great in this situation. A `Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent>` could be used to store a mapping of "name" -> object, then not only would you not need your switch statement anymore, but you would also be able to include new agents with ease by simply performing an Add operation.

To illustrate my point, I built upon your example, using the said dictionary to remove the need for the switch statement. The addition of new agents is left as an exercise (consult this if you need help: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-5.0)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var agentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ValorantAgent>();
        agentDictionary.Add("Jett", new ValorantAgent("Jett", "dash", "updraft", "smoke", "duelist"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Omen", new ValorantAgent("Omen", "smoke", "teleport", "flash", "controller"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Breach", new ValorantAgent("Breach", "seismic blast", "flash", "fusion charge", "initiator"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Reyna", new ValorantAgent("Reyna", "dismiss", "devour", "leer", "duelist"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Sova", new ValorantAgent("Sova", "Tracker dart", "Shock dart", "Drone", "Initiator"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Brimstone", new ValorantAgent("Brimstone", "Smoke", "Molly", "Stim Becon", "Controller"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Viper", new ValorantAgent("Viper", "Toxic Screen", "Poison Cloud", "Toxic Molly", "Controller"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Phoenix", new ValorantAgent("Phoenix", "Fire Molly", "Flash", "Fire Wall", "Duelist"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Raze", new ValorantAgent("Raze", "Grenade", "Boom Bot", "Blast Pack", "Duelist"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Sage", new ValorantAgent("Sage", "Healing Orb", "Slow Orb", "Wall", "Sentinal"));
        agentDictionary.Add("Cypher", new ValorantAgent("Cypher", "Camera", "tripwire", "Cage", "Sentinal"));
        agentDictionary.Add("KillJoy", new ValorantAgent("KillJoy", "Turret", "Molly", "Alarmbot", "Sentinal"));

        int PlayerChoice = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello User, What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] See current agents");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Add a agent");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Exit");

        PlayerChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(PlayerChoise)
        {
            case 1:

                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Pick an agent");

                string[] Agents = agentDictionary.Keys.ToArray(); //rewriting the names of all agents is not needed

                for (int i = 0; i < Agents.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {Agents[i]}");
                }

                int Selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                string selectedAgent = Agents[Selection];

                Console.WriteLine($"You selected {selectedAgent}");

                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {agentDictionary[selectedAgent].AgentName}, Ability 1: {agentDictionary[selectedAgent].AgentAbility1} Ability 2: {agentDictionary[selectedAgent].AgentAbility2}, Ability 3: {agentDictionary[selectedAgent].AgentAbility3}, Agent Type: {agentDictionary[selectedAgent].AgentType}");
                
                break; //case 1/see current agents break
            case 2://add agent case
                Console.Clear();
```

On a side note, there is also a small bug in the agent selection, where the user could type an integer greater (or smaller) than the array bounds, causing an IndexOutOfRangeException. Can you spot the problem and fix it?